# How to deal with disappearing texture due to mesh stretching? (2.80, Eevee & Cycles)

Tags: texturing

Unfortunately, I need to move the bones. But as you can see in the image, it doesn't take much at all for the texture to start disappearing.
[image: Texture partially lost due to stretching]

I understand that a stretched texture is expected when the mesh is stretched. However, I do not need the selected bones to bend more than that really. So, what would you say are my options? There has to be a workaround at least. 
Feel free to inspect the file: 
https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/7/a/7/7a7a878f9f3cf9c02d267f30dac59ff4707db3d5.blend

Comment: Behind the text the mesh is duplicated. When you bend the mesh with the armature the rear faces are overlapping the front faces and covering the text that's why it is vanishing.

Comment: I'll remove those inner faces... Thank you FFeller